# Getting "no key for given address or file" error when trying to unlock account in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I'm trying to unlock an ethereum user account using geth, but am getting an error message that doesn't make sense to me.

Here's what I do:

1) I start the geth console connected to the ropsten network:

```
geth --testnet console
```

2) Then I try to use the `personal.unlockAccount` method:

```
personal.unlockAccount('<account address>', '<key phrase>', 1000);
```

Then I get the error:

> Error: no key for given address or file

I'm not sure why I might be getting this message or what it means exactly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have your keystore file in the keystore folder? Do you have something returned when you run eth.accounts ?

Comment: It does appear to be. Is there a way to confirm that what I think is the keystore dir actually is?

Comment: When you launch geth, you have some information displayed. One of them is the path of the files. It chould be something like wherever_you_installed_geth/geth/keystore